# Using decorators from base class

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a class that inherits from another `base` class, and would like to use decorators

```py
class Base:
    def Checkpoint(func: Any) -> Any:
        def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return f"calling {func} from a decorator"

        return inner
```

```py
class RegularClass(Base):
    @Checkpoint
    def DoSomething1(self):
        print("Doing something 1")

    @Checkpoint
    def DoSomething2(self):
        print("Doing something 1")
```

It works if I move `Checkpoint` inside `RegularClass`; but I am hoping I would keep `Checkpoint` inside `Base` class, so I can reuse it across several classes

I am getting `Undefined name 'Checkpoint'` error when I try to instantiate `RegularClass` and use it. Was following [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-decorator-inside-a-class-in-python/), not sure what I am missing.

I have also tried `@Base.Checkpoint`, but that doesn't seem to work either. Here is the error I am getting

```
Base.Checkpoint() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
```

Not sure why it's adding the `()` after `Base.Checkpoint`? I don't need `()` with decorators, right?

Any ideas anyone? Python version: 3.11.4.

Comment: What doesn't work with `@Base.Checkpoint`?

Comment: In what way did `@Base.Checkpoint` not work? Could you also comment on why you want the decorator to be a (misbehaved) staticmethod instead of just a free standing function?

Comment: sorry; added the error for `Base.Checkpoint` in the post

Comment: Defining decorators inside a class (especially when you want to use them in another class) is usually not the best option.  The main exception would be if the decorator needs to have instance state, but in that case you need to instantiate the class before you can use the decorator.  MOST of the time it’s better for the decorator to be it’s own freestanding function as Brian suggested.

Comment: @scorpion35 How are you calling `DoSomething1(self)`?

Comment: `@Base.Checkpoint` works for me. `@Checkpoint` doesn't, but I don't think the scoping rules are supposed to work like that (the scope available from inside a class body has always confused me a little bit).

Comment: re: _"I don't need () with decorators, right?"_ There's nothing special about decorators when it come whether you need to write `()` or not. You _need_ to write `@foo()` instead of `@foo` if `foo` _returns_ a decorator when you call it, but isn't a decorator itself. Some decorators (like `dataclass`) implement a dual interface where they both _are_ a decorator and also _return_ a decorator when called with the right arguments. It all depends on what `foo` is and how it behaves.

Comment: Did you also want to call `func(self, *args, **kwargs)` from within `inner()`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to define your `Checkpoint` outside of your `Base` class? Even if your `RegularClass` is a subclass of `Base`, it can't access the decorator function. If you do:

```
def Checkpoint(func):
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return f"calling {func} from a decorator"
    return inner

class RegularClass:
    @Checkpoint
    def DoSomething1(self):
        print("Doing something 1")

    @Checkpoint
    def DoSomething2(self):
        print("Doing something 1")
```

then you won't get any errors. I also removed the type hints since they were also generating errors in my IDE (`"Any" is not defined.`).

Comment: Thanks! you are prolly missing an import `from typing import Any`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you intended to actually call your wrapped function right? This seems to work as I anticipated:

```py
class Base:
    def Checkpoint(func):
        def _wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print(f"calling {func} from a decorator")
            func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return _wrapper

class RegularClass(Base):
    @Base.Checkpoint
    def DoSomething1(self):
        print("Doing something 1")

    @Base.Checkpoint
    def DoSomething2(self):
        print("Doing something 2")

r = RegularClass()
r.DoSomething1()
r.DoSomething2()
```

That results in:

```
calling <function RegularClass.DoSomething1 at 0x7f4c3e753ee0> from a decorator
Doing something 1
calling <function RegularClass.DoSomething2 at 0x7f4c3e75a040> from a decorator
Doing something 2
```

If in the end, you want to force child classes to utilize a wrapper defined in the base, you would probably want to leverage a metaclass.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into metaclasses, bit new to python language